# query argument of mongoexport

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoexport

What is the right format of **query** argument of **mongoexport** utility?

While running the following command in the command line:

```
   mongoexport -h localhost:27000 -d dbName -c collName -q "{'time': { $gt: new Date('2014-01-28T12:00:00Z')}}" -o output.js
```

I'm getting the following error:

> connected to: localhost:27000 assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse:
>   FailedToParse: Expecting '}' or ',': offset:37

Reading [Mongo Export query arg](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/#cmdoption--query) and [JSONDocument docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/glossary/#term-json-document) haven't helped me to understand the expected format of query argument.

Running the same query in mongo shell succeeds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If:

```
>new Date ("2014-01-28T12:00:00Z").getTime()
1390910400000
```

You will have to construct your query as follows:

```
-q "{sendToServerTime: {\$gt: {\$date : 1390910400000}}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `new Date()` command. This no valid json. Try this:

```
mongoexport -h localhost:27000 -d DeploymentJan01 -c sensorsData -q '{sendToServerTime: { $gt: "2014-01-28T12:00:00Z"}}' -o output.js
```