# How to mongoexport with complex query

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I'm trying to run a mongoexport with the following query:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
db.GameHistory.find( { timeCreated: { $lte: d} } )
```

I want to export all documents with creation Date older then 3 month.
I tried this:

```
mongoexport --db game_server --collection GameHistory -q ' var d = new Date();d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);db.GameHistory.find( { timeCreated: { $lte: d} } )' --out /home/dev/file.json
```

and got this exception:

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '{': offset:0 of:db.GameHistory.find( { timeCreated: { $lte: new Date()} } )
```

Ideas?

Comment: May be you'll get some idea here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530209/query-argument-of-mongoexport), a little bit of tweaking should get you to the solution

Comment: -q can only accept a query predicate - so only a json document representing the query, it cannot evaluate arbitrary JS statements.

Comment: OK I understand I cant use js in the command line so how can I do a query with a changing date parameter?